# When using IMPORTHTML, how do i breakup the return data and only receive certain info?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using this formula to receive data in A3.

=importhtml("https://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$A$3,"Table",5)

Which returns:

GOOGL[NASD]

*Alphabet Inc.*

Communication Services | Internet Content & Information | USA

My question is how do I edit the formula where all I receive is the Communication Services?

I have tried using split function with it but I am not familiar enough with it to know how to input properly.

Comment: Is this excel, google sheet, libreoffice??

Comment: It is google sheets

Answer (score 0):

Use [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) to select specific elements in the list returned by `IMPORTHTML`, and [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to split the last element between `|`:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$A$3,"Table",5),3),"|"),1)
```

[image]